# Sorting array of objects by property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have this collection from DataBase:

```
var items = [{ 'Name':'Michael', 'TypeId':1 }
        { 'Name':'Max', 'TypeId':1 }
        { 'Name':'Andre', 'TypeId':1 }
        { 'Name':'Georg', 'TypeId':2 }
        { 'Name':'Greg', 'TypeId':3 }
        { 'Name':'Mitchell', 'TypeId':2 }
        { 'Name':'Ptro', 'TypeId':1 }
        { 'Name':'Helga', 'TypeId':1 }
        { 'Name':'Seruin', 'TypeId':2 }
        { 'Name':'Ann', 'TypeId':3 }
        { 'Name':'Marta', 'TypeId':2 }]
```

I need to sort this items by TypeId increasing.

Like that:

```
var itemsSorted = [{ 'Name':'Michael', 'TypeId':1 }
        { 'Name':'Max', 'TypeId':1 }
        { 'Name':'Andre', 'TypeId':1 }
        { 'Name':'Ptro', 'TypeId':1 }
        { 'Name':'Helga', 'TypeId':1 }
        { 'Name':'Georg', 'TypeId':2 }
        { 'Name':'Mitchell', 'TypeId':2 }
        { 'Name':'Marta', 'TypeId':2 }]
        { 'Name':'Seruin', 'TypeId':2 }
        { 'Name':'Greg', 'TypeId':3 }
        { 'Name':'Ann', 'TypeId':3 }
```

Is there any built in function in JavaScript that can sort array of objects by property?

Comment: You can do that with Angular `ng-repeat="items | orderBy: 'TypeId'"`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use `orderBy` filter.

```
var itemsSorted  = $filter('orderBy')(items, 'TypeId')
```

**On View**

```
ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'TypeId'"
```

By default filters are ascending(explicit would be `+TypeId`), you could use `-TypeId` to make it descending.

---

**Additional Stuff**

If you wanted to sort by multiple properties then do use array instead of `string` like `['TypeId', 'Name']`

```
ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: ['TypeId', 'Name']"
```

There is big performance benefit you get when you do manual filtering inside controller. where as filtering on view is slower as it evaluates `ng-repeat` express and bindings each time when digest cycle fire. Generally you won't see any performance hit in small collection, but in bigger collection you will see filtering on view will work slow.

Comment: do you know if there is a performance difference between on view vs. in controller?

Comment: @ivanivan check updated answer, I added it for you :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use js `sort` function & `ternary operator`

```
var items = [{ 'Name':'Michael', 'TypeId':1 },
            { 'Name':'Max', 'TypeId':1 },
            { 'Name':'Andre', 'TypeId':1 },
            { 'Name':'Georg', 'TypeId':2 },
            { 'Name':'Greg', 'TypeId':3 },
            { 'Name':'Mitchell', 'TypeId':2 },
            { 'Name':'Ptro', 'TypeId':1 },
            { 'Name':'Helga', 'TypeId':1 },
            { 'Name':'Seruin', 'TypeId':2 },
            { 'Name':'Ann', 'TypeId':3 },
            { 'Name':'Marta', 'TypeId':2 }]
    var sortedArray = items.sort(function(a,b){
     return a.TypeId >b.TypeId?1:a.TypeId <b.TypeId?-1:0
    })
    console.log(sortedArray);
```

[JSFIDDLE Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7uwm8sd0/11/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
var items = [{ 'Name':'Michael', 'TypeId':1 },
        { 'Name':'Max', 'TypeId':1 },
        { 'Name':'Andre', 'TypeId':1 },
        { 'Name':'Georg', 'TypeId':2 },
        { 'Name':'Greg', 'TypeId':3 },
        { 'Name':'Mitchell', 'TypeId':2 },
        { 'Name':'Ptro', 'TypeId':1 },
        { 'Name':'Helga', 'TypeId':1 },
        { 'Name':'Seruin', 'TypeId':2 },
        { 'Name':'Ann', 'TypeId':3 },
        { 'Name':'Marta', 'TypeId':2 }];


items.sort(function(a, b) { return a.TypeId - b.TypeId; })

console.table(items);

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(items, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

In a template:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'TypeId'">...</li>
```

In a controller/service:

```
vm.sortedItems = $filter('orderBy')(items, 'TypeId');
```

Comment: `return a.TypeId - b.TypeId;` would work as well! ;)