# How can I sort an array with multiple arrays within? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

So I am working on a Grid-based Tactical Battle System for RPG Maker MV (uses Javascript), and I am stuck on developing the turn order. My knowledge of what certain arrays are called is slim so I apologize in advance.

WHAT I AM DOING (simplified without the other classes):

```
var turnOrder = [];
var roll = (actor.agi - 10) + Math.randomInt(100);
var data = {
   id: actor._actorId,
   type: "player",
   init: roll
};
turnOrder.push(data);
```

And that loops throughout the party members, and then adds the enemy (by eventId) at the end.

WHAT I NEED HELP WITH: How would I sort the following example? (2 players + 1 enemy)

```
[{"id":1,"type":"player","init":27},
 {"id":2,"type":"player","init":4},
 {"id":1,"type":"enemy","init":17}]
```

How would I sort the above by "init" only? (in descending order)
I appreciate anyone and everyone in advance for this (I couldn't seem to find it via other searches).

Comment: Arrays in javascript inherit the `.sort` method. I think that would likely come up first in your searches if "javascript" and "sort" were mentioned together. .......... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting array of objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667731/sorting-array-of-objects-by-property)

Comment: I take it back - the .sort and => syntax actually work... huh.. surprising. Welp! Thank you all, got it to work now :) <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sort` to sort based on `init` in descending order

```js
pool=[{"id":1,"type":"player","init":27},
 {"id":2,"type":"player","init":4},
 {"id":1,"type":"enemy","init":17}]


  pool.sort((a,b)=>b.init-a.init)
  console.log(pool)
```

Comment: Oh... all this time I thought "=>" wasn't working... but this did it! WHOOT!!! Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```js
let arr = [{"id":1,"type":"player","init":27},
 {"id":2,"type":"player","init":4},
 {"id":1,"type":"enemy","init":17}];

function compare(a, b) {
  return a.init < b.init ? -1 : 1;
}

let sorted = arr.sort(compare);
console.log(sorted);
```